# VBA procedure cannot save file including dynamically created procedure

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a series of files automatically, although these files are yet only drafts I have to show them to relevant managers. So I want to be sure that they understand files they get are only first drafts.

I tried to include code into "Open, Workbook" event for each new created file using code from http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/VBE.aspx to show messagebox with some warning for the managers:

```
Sub CreateEventProcedure(wb, code)
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim LineNum As Long
Const DQUOTE = """" ' one " character

Set VBProj = wb.VBProject
Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

With CodeMod
    LineNum = .CreateEventProc("Open", "Workbook")
    LineNum = LineNum + 1
    .InsertLines LineNum, "    MsgBox " & DQUOTE & code & DQUOTE
End With

End Sub
```

When I am running the script I see, while the screen is updating or during debugging, that it creates the code correctly without an error...However when i open any of the newly created files the code is not there (i.e. the messagebox is not shown when the file is opened). Just fyi, I save files as .xlsm (macro-enabled)

```
wb.SaveAs Filename:=file_path, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

My tip is that somehow the files are saved without a VBA part...
Can you please help me?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me, as far as I have tried.

Comment: So you created a new file, used this to insert VBA code in it and saved it alright? and Msgbox pops up at start?

Comment: Far easier, IMO, to use a template workbook with the code already present in its `Open` event.

Comment: Delete - Rory said exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Rory, I agree that it is an easier way to do it, however user has to remember that he/she has to change parameters in two files, not just in one...moreover user doesnt have to be aware about VBA at all...So I want to avoid dividing "Master" file or teaching someone how to change event codes...

Comment: Why does the user need to do anything if you use a template?

Comment: @Vlad Yes, I put the `saveas`line in the same proc too, the file was correctly saved and the messagebox did show up.

Answer (score 0):

So your file doesnt contain any vba code at all? I think you are overcomplicating it or im just missing the intention but I always just use something like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    MsgBox "oi managers this is a draft"

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want to have in the files, however I dont want to write it into >50 files manually...I want to create it automatically, that is the point